# Better way for put the data inside db after validation codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

wich is the better way for put the data on the database after validation? i give you 2 example:

First

```
 $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Impossible to go on', 'required|xss_clean');
  if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE) { // check the field validation
      $username = $this->input->post('username'); // fist way
      $this->model_db->insert_username($username);
  }
```

Second

```
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Impossible to go on', 'required|xss_clean');
      if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE) { // check the field validation
          $username = $this->form_validation->set_value('login'); // second way
          $this->model_db->insert_username($username);
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think first one is the efficient way because inside of

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE) { }
```

means validation is ok i.e username field is not blank and now you can get the username and can insert it to database.

Comment: even shorter `if ($this->form_validation->run()) { }`

Comment: yes @Kyslik you are right.